# How to dynamically create histogram upon variable selection from drop down box in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create Shiny app where user will upload a csv file, upon uploading drop down box will populate with all the variables in dataset.

When user selects one of the variables from drop down box , corresponding histogram should be plotted in main panel.

Here is what I have done

ui.r File

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel( "Demand Forecast", "Flowserve"),
sidebarPanel(
fileInput('file1', 'Select csv file',accept=c('text/csv')
),
checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',',Tab='\t',  Semicolon=';' )
),
tags$hr(),
selectInput("product", "Select: ","")
 ),
mainPanel(tableOutput('contents'),

       plotOutput("hist")
      )
       ))
```

server.r  File

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)


    shinyServer(function(input,output,session){



    dataUpload<-reactive({

    inFile<-input$file1
    print(inFile)
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    dt_frame = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    updateSelectInput(session, "product", choices = names(dt_frame))
    })


    output$hist <- renderPlot({

    dataset<- dataUpload()
    hist(dataset[,dataset$product])

    })
  })
```

But when I run this app it gives me an error **object of type 'closure' is not subsettable**

Please Help..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a great example of why _not_ to use function names as object names - one reason is that it can lead to confusing error messages. `dt` is a function in base R (see `?dt`), and when you call `dt[, colm]` without the data frame `dt` existing in the scope, R will try to subset the function `dt`. So see if you can work out why your data frame `dt` is not within the scope of your `hist` call.

Comment: @jbaums  Thanks for ur rpl.. I have changed my server.r file Now when I run this app it gives me an error that X must b numeric

Comment: are the values passed to the `hist()` function numeric?

Comment: @ Keniajin  No.. actually i have directly picked up variables from drop box.So, it contains other type of variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of R shiny!

- You want to use selected column for histogram ->  `hist(dataset[,input$product])`
- Your reactive function doesn't return anything but you have written `dataset<- dataUpload()` -> add `return()` to the reactive function
- You also need error check in `renderPlot()`

Minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataUpload<-reactive({

    inFile<-input$file1
    print(inFile)
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    dt_frame = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    updateSelectInput(session, "product", choices = names(dt_frame))
    return(dt_frame)
    })

    #output$contents <- renderTable({
    #   dataset<- dataUpload()
    #   dataset
    #})
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
    # we need error check also here
    if(is.null(input$file1))
      return(NULL)
    dataset<- dataUpload()
    hist(dataset[,input$product])

    })


}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel( "Demand Forecast", "Flowserve"),
sidebarPanel(
fileInput('file1', 'Select csv file',accept=c('text/csv')
),
checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',',Tab='\t',  Semicolon=';' )
),
tags$hr(),
selectInput("product", "Select: ","")
 ),
mainPanel(tableOutput('contents'),

       plotOutput("hist")
      )
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```